# How to count the number of times a specific column is the maximum value in a row?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet that looks like this, which tracks attendance and order. On day 1, the order was [Alice, Bob, Catherine, Dave]. On day 2, the order was [Bob, Dave, Catherine], and Alice was absent:

| Date | Alice | Bob | Catherine | Dave |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10/1 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 10/2 | x | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| 10/3 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 10/4 | 1 | 0 | x | x |
| 10/5 | 0 | x | 1 | 2 |

I am trying to write a formula to get the total number of times each attendee went last. In other words, I want to count the number of times a name in a column is the `MAX` value for each date row, ignoring any `x`'s. Ideally, I would like a single formula that I could place in a single cell. If successful the resulting table would look like this:

| Attendee | # of times they went last |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | 2 |
| Bob | 0 |
| Catherine | 1 |
| Dave | 2 |

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [How much research effort is expected of stackoverflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)

Comment: @player0 10/3 and 10/4

Answer (score 1):

Find the `MAX` `BYROW`, then compare the `max` to each of the Attendees using `REDUCE`+`OFFSET`. If equal, create a `SUM`:

```
=LAMBDA(
  max,
  REDUCE(
    {"Attendee","#times"},
    B1:E1,
    LAMBDA(
      a,c,
      {a;c,SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET(c,1,0,5)=max)}
    )
  )
)(BYROW(B2:E6,LAMBDA(r,MAX(r))))
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(BYROW(B2:INDEX(E:E, MAX((A:A<>"")*ROW(A:A))), 
 LAMBDA(x, TEXTJOIN(, 1, IF(x=MAX(x), B1:E1, )))), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1 label count(Col1)''"))
```

[image]

with Bob:

```
=SORTN({QUERY(BYROW(B2:INDEX(E:E, MAX((A:A<>"")*ROW(A:A))), 
 LAMBDA(x, TEXTJOIN(, 1, IF(x=MAX(x), B1:E1, )))), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1 label count(Col1)''"); 
 TRANSPOSE({B1:E1;(B1:E1="")*1})}, 9^9, 2, 1, 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to add a column with the name of the last attendee. If, when you say you want a single formula, the reason is to don't show other cells, you can hide the column. Then you count how many times each name appears. This should be the result:

| Date | Alice | Bob | Catherine | Dave |  | last |  | Attendee | # of times they went last |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10/1 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |  | Dave |  | Alice | 2 |
| 10/2 | x | 0 | 2 | 1 |  | Catherine |  | Bob | 0 |
| 10/3 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 0 |  | Alice |  | Catherine | 1 |
| 10/4 | 1 | 0 | x | x |  | Alice |  | Dave | 2 |
| 10/5 | 0 | x | 1 | 2 |  | Dave |  |  |  |

Formula in cell G2 (under "last"), copied to the other cells of the column:

```
=INDEX(B$1:E$1,1,MATCH(MAX(B2:E2), B2:E2, 0))
```

It searches, only in that line, the maximum value. Gets the column and returns the correspondent name from the first line.

Formula in I2 (under "Attendee"):

```
=TRANSPOSE(B1:E1)
```

Transposes all names from the first line to the column.

Formula in J2, copied to the other cells of the column:

```
=COUNTIF(G$2:G,I2)
```

Counts how many times the name appears in column G.